# Turning a shulker into a vehicle by teleporting it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I was trying to make a plane/vehicle in Minecraft by teleporting Shulkers, using the /tp command. I made a repeating command block with this command:

```
/tp @e[type=Shulker] ~ ~0.1 ~
```

Even though they dont move the command block outputs this:

> [16:34:02] Teleported Shulker to 837.5, 59.5, 176.5

So am I doing anything wrong here? Is it because the shulkers are like a block?

I really thought this would work but they just stayed there. When I changes the     0.1 to 1 they telported up really really glitchy like teleporting everywhere.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Why not try using the /entitydata command instead with the motion tag? Might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shulkers automatically snap themselves to the grid when moved, so your teleport works, and then the shulker rounds its position and returns itself to where it last was.

Consider making it ride another entity like an armor stand, which stops this behavior.

`/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:ShulkerHolder,Marker:1b,Invisible:1b,NoGravity:1b,Passengers:[{id:shulker}]}`

You then teleport the armor stand like so: `/tp @e[type=armor_stand,name=ShulkerHolder] ~ ~.1 ~`

Comment: Would the shulker still be solid though?

Comment: No the shulker switches to soft. Best answer yet though +1

Comment: The shulker stays solid while riding an armor stand.

Comment: I've tested this [1.11.2] and they dont stay solid. I fall right through

Comment: At least its solid when its not teleporting.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The shulker does stay solid even while teleporting, but if you stand on top or push into it, your hitboxes will overlap and you'll fall through. Works nicely while riding on top as it goes straight though :)

Comment: Well nice answer anyway :) I'll check it

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your coordinates.

With a normal TP command, the location is relative to the sender. So `~ ~0.1 ~` is actually teleporting the shulker 0.1 blocks higher then the command block. And since the command block is stationary, so is the shulker.

To fix this problem, you must teleport the shulker relative to itself, using `/execute`:

```
execute @e[type=Shulker] ~ ~ ~ tp @p ~ ~0.1 ~
```

Comment: This isn't correct. `/tp` is teleporting relative to the target, not the sender. As a result, the shulker is teleported up 0.1 blocks from its own location each tick. `/teleport` is what teleports relative to the sender.

Answer (score -2):

/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:**PUT NAME HERE**,Invisible:1b,NoGravity:1b,Passengers:[{id:shulker}]}

/execute @e[type=armor_stand, name=**SAME NAME ABOVE**] ~ ~ ~ tp @p ~# ~# ~#

So, this is really the same command that the other guy did. /-=

Comment: Then why post a new answer?